# mysql string contained within a search string

Tags: mysql, regex, string, match

What I need seems simple, but I haven't been able to pull it off so far. Maybe it's just these late hours, or maybe it's not that simple after all, I don't know any more :)
So, here's the thing. I want to be able to check whether the **search string** from my site **contains** any of the fields from a particular column in my database. So, it would be the opposite of the usual one:

```
mysql_query("  
SELECT *  
FROM `table`  
WHERE `column` LIKE '%{$search}%'  
");
```

which looks for the fields with values where the **search string** is **contained**.
What would be the easiest way, using some regular expressions or...?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it the other way around

```
SELECT *  
FROM `table`  
WHERE '{$search}' LIKE concat('%', `column`, '%')
```

bear with me for the proper syntax for variable escaping for SQL-injection.

Comment: hmm, this makes sense, but it didnt work for me...no errors, just didnt filter the right ones out.

Comment: @spaceploitator: Hum.. would need to show table definition, few entries and expected results then.

Comment: the column field type is varchar in latin1_swedish_ci, with all the entries actually being 5 digit numbers. so i'd like to match a '12345' entry if i search for '123456'.

Comment: @spaceploitator: `select '123456' like concat('%', '12345', '%');` yield `true`, so maybe the syntax/escape of `'{$search}'` isn't correct?

Comment: yes, you were right, i was doing something wrong. thanks a lot! im sorry i cant give you a 1up :)

Answer (score 0):

your query is also good as you want.
but still you can try this.

You can search your string by using `MATCH() AGAINST()` statement in mysql.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(field11,field12) AGAINST ('searchstring')"); 


Here your field must be having Fulltext datatype.
```

This may work good.

Thanks.

Comment: hi chandresh, yes, i was familiar with match against, but it wont work for me cos of the datatype. thanks anyway!